# ST_MakeLine returns null

Tags: postgis

I am working with this query:

```
SELECT ST_MakeLine(route.geom ORDER BY seq)  as test
    FROM (SELECT * FROM pgr_fromAtoB('way',48.24287652969359,33.85220534163203,48.24991464614867,33.85092228417727  )) As route
```

the above query returns a null value. I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_fromAtoB('way',48.24287652969359,33.85220534163203,48.24991464614867,33.85092228417727  )
```

this query works fine and returns a set of columns with a geom (line) and seq columns witch is sequence of parts of lines.

I think I am doing something wrong with ST_MakeLine but can not find where it is.
Can you please help me find the mistake? Does `St_makeline` work fine with a series of line geometries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're using the function defined in the [postgis examples here?](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/wrapper.html)

If you want to collect the line geometries output from that function into one mutiline feature, use **ST_Collect()** to merge the ordered line geometries into a multiline, then **ST_LineMerge()** to get a single geometry, for example:-

```
select 
    ST_LineMerge(
        ST_Collect(geom)
    )
FROM pgr_fromAtoB('ways',-3.17186,55.97062,-3.20287,55.95739);
```

or create a table, load into qgis to visualise

```
create table quickview as (
    select ST_LineMerge(
        ST_Collect(geom)
    ) FROM pgr_fromAtoB('ways',-3.17186,55.97062,-3.20287,55.95739)
);
```

Here's an example I did from an OSM import of Edinburgh:-

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much,Yes I have some multilinestings and when I marged them it returns a linestring

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be difficult to diagnose this without knowing what `pgr_fromAtoB` returns. It's not a **pgRouting** function so presumably it's something you have added yourself?

But that aside, [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) takes either a set, two points or an array or parameters, which it doesn't sound like your function provides. IT looks like you might need to either modify your `pgr_fromAtoB` function or transform the output with another function, but without knowing what that function does it's hard to say.

Comment: Hi,pgr_fromAtoB returns a set of rows of lines which is the direction from A to B,I have get this function from this workshop workshop.pgrouting.org